# How to load geojson received from ajax call

Tags: google-maps, geojson

How can I load GEOJson data on google map? I tried in different ways but it doesn't work..
I don't have data saved in file.json..
I have data in this form:

```
var data = {
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry" : {
  "type" : "Point",
  "coordinates" : [125.6, 10.1]
},
"properties" : {
  "name" : "Dinagat Islands"
  }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your existing code to create a mpa and load the data in your question (even if it doesn't work)? Why do you have a restriction on the format of the data?  Is it a separate file?  Are you loading it using the [Google Maps data layer](http://jsfiddle.net/U58qt/2/)?

Answer (score 2):

Check the developer docs:

**Importing Data - What is GeoJSON?**

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data